# Found a swap file by the name ".git/.MERGE_MSG.swp"

Tags: java, git, svn, version-control, github

I tried to `pull origin branschName`

and got this strange error:

```
error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'.
Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.


E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name ".git/.MERGE_MSG.swp"
          owned by: eladb   dated: Tue Aug 20 10:52:03 2013
         file name: ~eladb/MyWorkspace/Client/.git/MERGE_MSG
          modified: no
         user name: eladb   host name: Elads-MacBook-Pro-2.local
        process ID: 29959 (still running)
While opening file ".git/MERGE_MSG"
             dated: Tue Aug 20 10:53:11 2013
      NEWER than swap file!

(1) Another program may be editing the same file.
    If this is the case, be careful not to end up with two
    different instances of the same file when making changes.
    Quit, or continue with caution.

(2) An edit session for this file crashed.
    If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r .git/MERGE_MSG"
    to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
    If you did this already, delete the swap file ".git/.MERGE_MSG.swp"
    to avoid this message.

Swap file ".git/.MERGE_MSG.swp" already exists!
[O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (Q)uit, (A)bort:
```

how to fix this?

Comment: Remove `.git/.MERGE_MSG.swp` and attempt ...

Comment: as move it to recycle bin? what is that file?

Comment: It's a swap file created by `vi`.  It seems to have been left over somehow.

Comment: @devnull You should probably suggest that as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that a swap file created by `vi` has been somehow left undeleted.

Remove `.git/.MERGE_MSG.swp` and attempt the `git merge` again.